# Do I see myself ... vs Do I look like

Tags: sentence-meaning

About the meaning of the sentence below:

> Do I see myself fatter than I am?

Is it the same as saying:

> Do I look like fatter than I am?

The reason I'm asking about this question is when I used google translate to translate another language to English then I reverted the translation, instead of getting "**Do I look like....**" I got "**Do I see myself...**". Is that even used in English conversation? Are they the same expression?

I tried to google "Do I see myself..." and I found the sentence I've mentioned earlier. Then I wonder if the first and the second has the same meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say either one, they have slightly different meanings

> Do I see myself fatter than I am?

Is asking if you yourself see yourself fatter than you are

and

> Do I look fatter than I am?

Would be the right way to say this and it would be more of a question to someone, like

> Do I look fatter than I am in this dress?

for example.